# Encryption or hashing clarification

Tags: encryption

I am learning about encryption and hashing and how it works and I saw this as an example for a multiple choice:

```
sha256:1000:Om7yaZJtN8Ja1d+ogWGSz279wrh8hU6Q:w/yQtfpNEOosSLCjLzg131jxXJ5018WU
```

I'm confused on that the first two portions represent? 
Is this a sha256 encryption? I counted 65 characters and I believe sha256 has 64.

Can anyone shed some light on what example I have here?

Comment: There are a lot of misunderstandings in you question, so it's hard to know exactly which part to address first. Where did you get this example, and what does it claim to be? There is no such thing as "sha256 encryption" as a starting point. And number of characters (in a Base64 encoding) is not the same thing as number of bytes. But to your example is strange, so starting with where you got it and what it claims to be would be helpful. I suspect it's KDF output, but I don't recognize it immediately.

Comment: It would make sense yes, hash for e.g. PBKDF2 (a password hash), then iteration count 1000 (which is the old default), then a base 64 salt followed by the hash, also in base 64, separated by colons. Without the password, that's all nice and dandy, but impossible to validate. I would advice a migration to https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ but without password.... Note too that the last part only has 24 bytes, which is a bit strange, because you would expect 256 bits / 32 bytes for SHA-256.

Comment: Thank you Maarten Bodewes! it was from my textbook for my class but I continued reading and reread and I notices it's creating a hash. It appear the last portion it is base64 encoding the pbkdf2 hash algorithm, the password given the interactions and the hash byte size. It's still all new to me but I will continue to read up on it